# One Vote per IP address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to implement a voting system where votes are limited by the voters ip_address.

I have a post model which has many_votes and the votes belong_to the post model.

My question is how and where do I define the "current_user" and how can do i implement this in the view.

Currently I am creating votes like this:

```
<%= link_to(post_votes_path(post), :method => 'post') do %>
<%= song.votes.size %>
```

Works fine except anyone can vote and i want to stop that. Please i am not looking for a gem I am just trying to learn this functionality from scratch.

Cheers.

Here is my Posts controller code:

```
def create
@post = Post.new(params[:post])

respond_to do |format|
  if @post.save
    format.html { redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
  end
end
end
```

and vote controller code for create action:

```
def create
@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
@vote = @post.votes.create
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to root_url }
  #format.js 
end
end
```

Comment: Can you also tell how are your users stored?

Comment: Current I have no users table, I am thinking of adding a voter_id to the votes table ?

Comment: You should add a column 'voter_ip' in your Vote table, and put it there the ip of the voter : `@post.votes.create(voter_ip: request.remote_ip)` (the variable `request` is only available in Controllers, when you receive a request) And then do like @Gene said, add a `validates :voter_id, uniqueness: true` in your Vote model.

Comment: Thank you AnkitG and MrYoshiji, everything works fine until i try to vote for another post. Does not seem to work. Looks like one i vote for something i cannot vote for anything else. Any ideas ?

Comment: You do understand that there are a number of ways people can hide their actual IP number, or change it by messing with their networking gear. One vote/one IP would not last long if people want to spoof it.

Comment: Yes I do still learning rails just wanted to understand how its done. Thanks for the heads up. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the MrYoshiji suggests, you should add a voter_ip column to your votes table.

You can add this AR `where` clause to your posts / votes controller

```
if @post.votes.where(voter_ip: request.remote_ip).empty?
  @post.votes.create(vote: params[:post_vote])
end
```

This will check of this post has any votes from the current ip. In case no votes are recorded, a new vote is added with the param value of `post_vote`

In case you prefer to add a constraint to your `vote` model, you need to do a scoped validation.

```
validates_uniqueness_of :voter_ip, scope: :post_id
```

When using the scope parameter the uniqueness constraint is applied to the combination of `voter_ip` and `post_id`, instead of `voter_ip` alone.

Comment: Scoped Validation was what I is what i was looking for. Worked perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: in Rails 4, you can use where.not clause. http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/not-equal-support-for-active-record-queries-rails-4-countdown-to-2013

Comment: Cheers, just wondering how i can call something like "vote_for" in a view. e.g check if the current users ip_ has voted for a post.

Answer (score 1):

The votes table needs in `ip` column with a unique validation constraint.  Then the controller's save will fail if you try to record more than one vote per ip, which you can detect and use to flash an error.  You must post your controller code in order to get a better answer.

Comment: Just wondering if rails automatically detects the ip column and matches it to an ip address ?

Comment: @Joshua No, you need to link these together in your controller.

Comment: cheers Gene. Having the same problem as outlined above. Sure enough its restricting my vote based on the uniqueness of my ip. But it isn't allowing me vote for anything else. I wanted to restrict vote per post not one vote only. Any ideas ?